# Connect 4 project for three players with PyGame graphics

Tags: python, pygame, connect-four

I am currently working on a Connect 4 game for a project and it works. We added support so that it can be played by 3 players instead of 2. I know there is multiple instances of repeated code or un-optimized functions or code. I would appreciate any help on that front.

Regarding the 3 player connect 4 we pretty much had it act just like normal connect 4 but with 3 players. Player 1 is red, Player 2 is yellow and Player 3 is green. All 3 players are trying to get "Connect 4" like normal and prevent the other players from getting "Connect 4". We are doing that in hopes of adding some complexity in play and add another variable for players to have to deal with while playing.

````
import sys
import numpy as np
import pygame
import math

# Global Values for the Game
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

ROW_COUNT = 7
COLUMN_COUNT = 8
SQUARE_SIZE = 75

WIDTH = COLUMN_COUNT * SQUARE_SIZE
HEIGHT = (ROW_COUNT + 1) * SQUARE_SIZE

RADIUS = int(SQUARE_SIZE / 2 - 5)


# Function to Create the Board Full of Zeros
def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT))
    return board


# Function for Dropping the Player Pieces
def drop_piece(board, row, col, piece):
    board[row][col] = piece


# Function to See Where the Player Drops is Valid
def is_valid(board, col):
    return board[ROW_COUNT - 1][col] == 0


# Function to See Where the Next Open Row to Place Player Piece
def next_open_row(board, col):
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
        if board[r][col] == 0:
            return r


# Function to Print the Actual Board Because it is Flipped
def print_board(board):
    print(np.flip(board, 0))


# Function to Check the Multiple Winning Move Cases
def winning_move(board, piece):
    # Check Horizontal Locations
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT - 3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r][c + 1] == piece and board[r][c + 2] == piece and board[r][c + 3] == \
                    piece:
                return True

    # Check Vertical Locations
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT - 3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r + 1][c] == piece and board[r + 2][c] == piece and board[r + 3][c] == piece:
                return True

    # Check Positive Diagonals
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT - 3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT - 3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r + 1][c + 1] == piece and board[r + 2][c + 2] == piece and board[r + 3][c + 3] == piece:
                return True

    # Check Negative Diagonals
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT - 3):
        for r in range(3, ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r - 1][c + 1] == piece and board[r - 2][c + 2] == piece and board[r - 3][c + 3] == piece:
                return True


# Draws the Graphical Game Board
def draw_board(board):
    # This nested for loop makes the empty starting board
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (c * SQUARE_SIZE, r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (
                int(c * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2), int(r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)

    # This nested for loop is what is used to fill the board in with the player pieces
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == 1:  # Fill the board with Player 1 pieces
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (
                    int(c * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2), HEIGHT - int(r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)

            if board[r][c] == 2:  # Fill the board with Player 2 pieces
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (
                    int(c * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2), HEIGHT - int(r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)

            elif board[r][c] == 3:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (
                    int(c * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2), HEIGHT - int(r * SQUARE_SIZE + SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)

    pygame.display.update()


# Function to track the mouse movement
def track_mouse():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:  # Tracks the mouse motion
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, WIDTH, SQUARE_SIZE))
        posx = event.pos[0]
        if turn == 0:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, (posx, int(SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
        if turn == 1:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, (posx, int(SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
        elif turn == 2:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (posx, int(SQUARE_SIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
    pygame.display.update()


# Graphical representation of dropping the piece
def draw_drop_piece(event, turn):
    game_over = False
    colors = (RED, YELLOW, GREEN)  # Container to Store Colors for easy calling
    if turn in (0, 1, 2):  # Checks to See if its Players Turn
        posx = event.pos[0]
        col = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARE_SIZE))

        if is_valid(board, col):  # Checks Every Turn if Where the Player is Putting Their Piece is Valid
            row = next_open_row(board, col)
            drop_piece(board, row, col, turn + 1)

            if winning_move(board, turn + 1):  # Checks Every Turn if the Player Won
                label = FONT.render("PLAYER {} WINS!".format(turn + 1), 1, colors[
                    turn])  # Format function allows to easily change a string in code depending on values
                screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                game_over = True

        else:
            label = FONT.render("Enter Valid Spot", 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
            game_over = None  # If the player made an invalid move it returns a none value
        print(turn)
    return game_over


def start_menu(screen):
    click = False

    while True:
        label = FONT.render("Main Menu", 1, BLUE)
        screen.blit(label, (WIDTH / 4, 40))

        posx, posy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        button_1 = pygame.Rect(WIDTH / 2, 200, 300, 70)
        button_2 = pygame.Rect(WIDTH / 2, 300, 300, 70)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, button_1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, button_2)

        start_text = FONT.render("Start", 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(start_text, (WIDTH / 3, 200))

        quit_text = FONT.render("Quit", 1, WHITE)
        screen.blit(quit_text, (WIDTH / 3, 300))

        if button_1.collidepoint((posx, posy)):
            if click:
                return True
        if button_2.collidepoint((posx, posy)):
            if click:
                sys.exit()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Exiting the game
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()

    board = create_board()  # Creates Board
    print_board(board)  # Prints Board
    game_over = False  # The Game Isn't Over as it Just Started
    turn = 0  # Player One Starts First
    total_spaces = ROW_COUNT * COLUMN_COUNT
    FONT = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 50)
    SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

    start_menu(screen)

    draw_board(board)
    pygame.display.update()

    while not game_over:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # Exiting the game
                sys.exit()

            track_mouse()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, WIDTH, SQUARE_SIZE))

                game_over = draw_drop_piece(event, turn)

                print_board(board)
                draw_board(board)

                # This makes sure the turn indicator alternates between 1 and 0
                # Also checks if the player made a valid move and if they didn't it doesn't move to the next turn
                if game_over is not None:
                    turn = (turn + 1) % 3
                    total_spaces -= 1

                # Checks to see if the total empty spaces are 0 if so that means its a tie
                if total_spaces <= 0:
                    label = FONT.render("TIE!", 1, BLUE)
                    screen.blit(label, (40, 10))
                    print_board(board)
                    draw_board(board)
                    game_over = True

                if game_over:
                    pygame.time.wait(5000)
```
````

Comment: At least for me, your code isn't working (Python 3.9.4 on MacOS). It prints out some pygame boilerplate and a grid of zeros to the terminal and opens up a pygame window, but the window is mostly featureless (all black with a small blue rectangle and two small white rectangles). The window doesn't respond to any basic mouse clicks or keyboard presses. Does your program run only on certain kinds of systems? If so, you might want to add those qualifications to your question.